# What is a positioned ancestor?

Tags: css, css-position

I am reading the "Positioning Techniques" of this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction) on MDN.
It talks about "Absolute positioning elements can be fixed to a position relative to its nearest positioned ancestor element".

My understanding of "positioned ancestor" is an ancestor with any position property other than static. But I need expert opinions to verify my thought.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe, so until I find the appropriate target, I'll say here: your understanding is correct. Not sure what wiggle room there is for another interpretation to begin with.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When referring to *positioned ancestor* we mean the closest ancestor to the element with a set `position` value, other than `static` (which is default).

So there are two assumptions here:

1. In case there are more than one *positioned ancestor*s we mean **the closest**.
2. In case there is an ancestor with a set `position:static` (presumably set by JavaScript, in order to change the "positioned ancestor") we don't mean that ancestor.

Why is this important? Because the *"positioned ancestor"* is the reference from which properties like `left` and `top` are calculated, when the descendant is given `position:absolute`. It's also called "the reference element/parent" of the descendant.
Also, if this closest ancestor has a set `z-index` (other than `auto`), it creates a stacking context for its descendants.

Comment: What do you mean by the closest? Can this be parent or sibling? If it can be both, which is closest of the two of them?

Comment: @ReidunMarie, *"closest ancestor"* only means **ancestor** (parent). Not sibling, nor child. See [closest()](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest) defined in HTML specification.

Answer (score 2):

[From the W3C:](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Containing_blocks)

> In this case the containing block is the nearest positioned ancestor.
>   By “positioned” I mean an element whose position property is set to
>   relative, absolute or fixed—in other words, anything except normal
>   static elements.

[Long description for example illustrating positioning with respect to a positioned ancestor](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/images/longdesc/flow-abs-rel-desc.html)

> a containing block established by a relatively positioned ancestor
>   ("outer").

And [CSS Module 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/), search for "positioned ancestor" on that page.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu So you are saying Tim Berners-Lee is wrong? I'm sure you are thinking I linked to W3Schools but I did not. The links are to the CSS specs an articles from the W3C. In any case, your statement has not been true about W3Schools either for a number of years.

Comment: You are correct, my previous comment was based on the wrong impression  you linked W3Schools. I apologize and I assure you I meant to help.