# Overlap list with the rest of the page

Tags: html, css, vue.js

[image]

[image]

I am building a Vue component that search through an API call a list of cities with the input text. I need that the list displayed does not expand the header component, and overlap the first image (a sky on the picture). I try with z-index, but is not working.

Any other idea of implementation is welcome. I try with dropdown, but is not writable.

Edit: sorry, I forgot to add the code.

```
<!--template-->
<div class="input-city">
        <input  v-model="input" type="text" ref="citySearch" />        
        <div class="cities-list">
          <span
            v-for="city in results"
            :key="city.id"
            @click="setCity(city)"
            class="city-item"
          >
            {{ city.name }}, {{ city.region }}, {{ city.country }}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
// styles
.input-city {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cities-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.city-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your current HTML and JS?

Comment: We need to see your implementation to be able to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is known as *absolute positioning* and is achieved by giving the element a `position` style value of `absolute` or `fixed`.

Technically, the element is taken outside of what's called *"flow content"*. By taking an element out of flow content, the remaining flow content elements behave like the absolute positioned one wasn't present.
The actual position of the absolute positioned element is relative to

- its [closest positioned ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784777/what-is-a-positioned-ancestor) if `position` is set to `absolute`
- its closest viewport if the `position` is set to `fixed`.

In your example, this should work:

```
.input-city {
  position: relative;
}
.input-city .cities-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

1. `position: relative` on `.input-city` makes that element the closest positioned element for `.cities-list`.
2. `position: absolute` takes `.cities-list` out of content flow
3. `top: 100%` gives it a top margin equal to its parents' height.

A typical styling solution in such cases is to give the overlapping element a `background-color` and a `box-shadow`, so it's distinguishable from the content it overlaps (but those are implementation details).

To find out more about how `position` (a fundamental concept in CSS) works, you might want to start with this article: [CSS Positioning 101](https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101/).

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I started styding CSS with flexbox to positionate elements, so the position attribute is something misterious for me.

Comment: `position` and `display` are not enemies. They're more like brothers or allies. You'll definitely need both to tame your elements.