# How to make ::before appear before every wrapped line of a div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div element that has a border-left on a `::before`. It works perfectly on one line, but when I wrap the line, the `border-left` only covers the first line. How can I spread that line to the entire height of the div element? I've tried `height` but that doesn't seem to change it at all.

```css
#chatbox {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

#chatbox div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
}

#chatbox div::before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border-left: 3px solid gray;
  height: 1230px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
<div>
qwerty: 562243835622438356224383562243835622438356224383562243835622438356224383562243835622438356224383
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I've tried height but that doesn't seem to change it at all."_ - of course it doesn't, because by default, pseudo elements have `display: inline`, and therefor width and height _must_ not work on them. A height in percentage will not help you here either though, for that the parent would need to have an explicit height as well. You should probably do this via `flexbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the div position relative so it stays in its original place but be a "[positioned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784777/what-is-a-positioned-ancestor)" so its child (the `::before` element) can be absolute positioned relatively to it.

Make the `::before` `top` and `bottom` `0` so it stretches the pseudo element size.
add left to make offset.

```css
#chatbox {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

#chatbox div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

#chatbox div::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 3px solid gray;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-3px; /* or any other offset */
  position: absolute;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
<div>
qwerty: 562243835622438356224383562243835622438356224383562243835622438356224383562243835622438356224383
</div>
</div>
```