# Why is CSS positioned to grand ancestor and not immediate ancestor?

Tags: html, css

Why is CSS positioned to grand ancestor and not immediate ancestor?

### Context

I'm watching a MERN stack Udemy course and we are on CSS. we are building a little blog post but I'm getting stuck on one specific part.

Using Safari and tried chrome

### What I've tried

Sorry for this basic question but ive tried ChatGPT and google with no avail. Ive also tried some Discord servers that do web development but no response.

### Issue

The issue I am facing is that the button in the div `alert` is being put to the right of the div called `container` and not the right of the div called `content`. I glance back at the instructor's code but it seems identical.

I asked chatGPT and it said that when you use `position: absolute` it makes the position based on the ancestor which  is the reason why I don't understand what is wrong cause the ancestor is content.

### Code

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    /* background-color: red; */
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: max-content;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

header a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #ff006e;
}

h1, p{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.left-sidebar{
    /* background-color: blue; */
    width: 65%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 10px;
}

.right-sidebar{
    /* background-color: yellow; */
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;

    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.alert button{
    background: #bc6c25;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- header -->
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>CSS Layout Project</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos numquam ad quis assumenda? Minus, eius rerum, deserunt excepturi suscipit quod quia et sequi at qui iure quibusdam, quae labore ad!</p>
    <a href="#">View more!</a>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- end header -->

<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- right side bar -->
  <div class="right-sidebar">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Node JS</h1>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/09/29/20/28/motocross-8284539_1280.jpg" , alt="idk">

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, dolorum consequatur. Officia ut facere officiis qui odit eligendi quis, rem adipisci distinctio assumenda facilis sint laboriosam illo ipsam! Vero, incidunt.</p>
      <a href="#"> Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- left side bar -->
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Node JS</h1>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/09/29/20/28/motocross-8284539_1280.jpg" , alt="idk">

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, dolorum consequatur. Officia ut facere officiis qui odit eligendi quis, rem adipisci distinctio assumenda facilis sint laboriosam illo ipsam! Vero, incidunt.</p>
      <a href="#"> Read more</a>

      <div class="alert">
        <button>New</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If parent has `position: relative`, then the child with absolute position will take this parent to position itself relative to this element.

Comment: So make the div `content` have position relative? @Klaassiek

Comment: @Sean yes it does thanks! I made `content` relative. I will answer my question

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

The `position: absolute` will only be absolute based on its nearest ancestor with a position that is not static (default)

To solve this issue, you must make `content` div's position to `relative`

This post goes more in debt on this topic.

[What is a positioned ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784777/what-is-a-positioned-ancestor)